# How to configure Samba to use Windows's login ID?

Tags: samba, authentication, active-directory

I'm trying to access the Linux share folder from Windows using Windows's domain authentication. I come across the integration of `Windows Active Directory` into Samba on a Linux box, thus I have this being configure in `smb.conf`:

```
# LDAP settings
        passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx
        ldap suffix = DC=org,dc=huahsin,dc=IT
        ldap user suffix = OU=Users,OU=Tech,OU=MY
        ldap admin dn = CN=AccountA,OU=Users,OU=Tech,OU=MY,DC=org,DC=huahsin,DC=IT
        ldap passwd sync = yes
```

And this is how I configure to my share folder:

```
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
   path = /home/huahsin/share
```

Anyhow I'm still not able to access my share folder. May I know what are the missing part in Samba configuration in order to authenticate through Windows's login ID when accessing a Linux share folder?

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure winbind, so you need to install and configure kerberos as well
edir `/etc/krb5.conf`
something like this:

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
        default_tgs_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5 des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5 des3-hmac-sha1
        default_tkt_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5 des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5 des3-hmac-sha1
        ticket_lifetime = 24000
        default_realm = YOUR.DOMAIN.COM
        dns_lookup_realm = false
        dns_lookup_kdc = false

[realms]
        YOUR.DOMAIN.COM = {
        kdc = your.ads.com
        admin_server = your.ads.com

        }

[domain_realm]
 .your.domain.com = YOUR.DOMAIN.COM
 your.domain.com = YOUR.DOMAIN.COM

[kdc]
 profile = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.conf

[appdefaults]
 pam = {
   debug = false
   ticket_lifetime = 36000
   renew_lifetime = 36000
   forwardable = true
   krb4_convert = false
 }
```

then `smb.conf` on relevant part:

```
[global]
        workgroup = YOUR-GROUP
        realm = YOUR.DOMAIN.COM
        netbios name = SERVER-NAME
        winbind separator = -
        winbind uid =  1000-1000000
        winbind gid =  1000-1000000
        winbind enum users = yes
        winbind use default domain = yes
        security = ADS
        encrypt passwords = yes
        client use spnego = no
        auth methods = winbind
```

then you need to have admin rights to join the linux box to the domain

```
net ads join -Uadminuser -d2
```

you will get something like this

```
Using short domain name -- YOUR-GROUP
Joined 'SERVER_NAME' to realm 'your-domain.com
```

then start the services winbind smb nmb in centos for example is

```
service smb start
service nmb start
service winbind start
```

check if the server was joined

```
net ads testjoin
Join is OK
```

check for a user

```
wbinfo -i username
```

or list the groups in the ADS

```
wbinfo -g
```

or list the users

```
wbinfo -u
```

ping the service

```
wbinfo -P

checking the NETLOGON dc connection to "your.ads.com" succeeded
```

Configure a share folder

```
[share_name]
        path = /path_to_share
        valid users = user1 user1
```

Comment: In smb.conf, why security type is ads? why not domain?